# depmix function to fit two state gamma distribution

Tags: r, markov, gamma

I am using depmixS4 package in R. I have a data that looks like a gamma distribution, and I am assuming that there are two states. I would like to fit two-state gamma distribution to my data in R. The following is my code:

```
mod <- depmix(freq ~ 1, data = mod.data, nstates = 2, family = gamma()) # use gamma 
fit.mod <- fit(mod)
```

However, it seems like I have an error because I am not passing an argument in the family = gamma() part. It works fine if I just use family = gaussian(). Can someone help me with this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Does capitalizing Gamma() solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Using a gamma distribution can provide issues with unsuitable starting values, so be sure to supply suitable ones when using the gamma family.